# Atmosphere invalidade Spring Security Session

Tags: tomcat, websocket, jboss7.x, atmosphere

I put some informations of my problem like codes, app, etc, on this link:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/atmosphere-framework/yRimVEmOYwg

The problem is, with JBoss EAP 6.1 (JBoss As 7.2) after send some message to broadcast Atmosphere invalidate the spring security session, but with Tomcat this problem does not occur.

Please someone can help-me?

Comment: I just found out that this problem is only occurring with 2.0.0.RC3 version, with version 1.0.15 is not happening

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and i searched lot for it but could not got any solution.
Then i got temporary solution to save spring security session during atmosphere notifications.
It is by escaping your methods url which contains broadcaster in it. just use `<http pattern="url_that_contain_broadcast" security="none" />` in your spring security, before  security defined.

Comment: This solved my problem: `<http pattern="/primepush/**" security="none" />`

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Work around I used in atmosphere was

```
if( (session.getCreationTime() - current Time) > session alive time )
then remove atmosphere resource. 
send "Redirect To login page message"
```

then using **javascript** I redirect user to **login page**.

Comment: This would be like telling your customers to just restart their car if it suddenly turns off on the middle of a highway...